# False vacua and the effective action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

The [effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\Gamma[\phi]$ of a (scalar) field theory described by the action $S[\phi]$, can be computed in the "background field method" by shifting $S[\phi + \phi_b]$, where $\phi_b$ is a spacetime-constant background field, and computing the $1$PI $0$-point diagrams. The minimum of the effective action describes the true expectation value $\langle\phi\rangle$.

My question is whether the effective action formalism extends to false-vacua (or pseudostable vacua) that are only *local* minima of the effective action. Do local (but not global) minima of the effective action correspond to physical pseudostable field configurations?

Edit: To be clear, I'm only interested in the effective potential, which is a simpler object than the full $1$PI effective action (the distinction is clarified in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action)).

Comment: By "false-vacua", do you mean: @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay

Comment: I do expect a false vacuum to decay if it exists, although my question is concerning whether I can use the 1PI effective action to determine if one exists in the first place.

Comment: To be clear, to find the effective action, you must take $\phi_b \equiv \phi_b(x)$ to be spacetime _dependent_. However, if you're only interested in the effective potential you can take $\phi_b$ to be a constant.

Comment: Yes - ultimately I am only interested in the effective potential, provided it is valid at a false vacuum.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the point - isn't this what people do? (https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6497, e.g. Fig. 5), if you have a metastable vacuum, then you are in a local minima?

Comment: @QCD_IS_GOOD yeah it seems to be what people do - I'm just not 100% clear on the justification. I think the statement is that $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial\phi} = J_\phi$, so setting the source $J_\phi = 0$, we find the vacua as the minima of $\Gamma$. However, I'm confused because the full effective potential should be convex -- typically we just join up the minima with a line (as one would do for the free energy of thermodynamics), but, assuming $\Gamma$ is smooth, this procedure only leaves in tact the global minimum. The local minima are all *inside* the convex hull.

Comment: If you haven't already seen, Peskin and Schroeder discusses this point in Section 11.3; from what I gather, you convexify the effective potential due to the possible presence of bubbles of both local minima (in appropriate ratios). I'd argue then that this is more of a technicality - the local minima themselves (before convexifying) are still physically meaningful, they serve as the ground states that can appear.

Comment: Yeah I remember reading that. I suppose that perturbation theory is sensitive only to the local properties of the effective potential, so that calculating $\Gamma$ is not equivalent to solving a theory, since there are non-perturbative effects that are not captured by 1PI diagrams. I can believe that it is self-consistent to work with $\Gamma$ around a local minimum provided the timescales involved are shorter than the tunneling rate.